# Automatic cross reference prefix from different sections in figures, tables, etc

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, cleveref

Is there a way that `\cref` can be set up such that it appends a prefix to references of figures placed in the Appendix?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{The first section}\label{sec:1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:MainBodyFig}
\end{figure}

This is a reference to \cref{fig:MainBodyFig} and another reference for \cref{fig:AppendixFig}

\begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Fig.}
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \section{Appendix}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:AppendixFig}
    \end{figure}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image: What I generate]

And the result I would like to have.
[image: What I want]

I would like to have this automatic such that I can move figures in between sections without having to manually change the prefixes in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by defining a new cross-reference name using `crefname`. This new name can then be assigned to the figure environment by using `crefalias` just after `\begin{appendices}`as shown in the following example. This approach can also be extended to tables, sections, ... .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\crefname{appendixfigure}{supplementary fig.}{supplementary fig.}

\begin{document}
\section{The first section}\label{sec:1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:MainBodyFig}
\end{figure}

This is a reference to \cref{fig:MainBodyFig} and another reference for \cref{fig:AppendixFig}.

\begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Fig.}
    \crefalias{figure}{appendixfigure}
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \section{Appendix}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:AppendixFig}
    \end{figure}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]